# Continuous Integration with Jasmine and Play framework?

Tags: scala, jenkins, continuous-integration, jasmine, bamboo

Were doing some TDD at uni and I'm wondering if it is easy enough to get continuous integration  with a tool like Jenkins or Bamboo for a javascript based app using the Play Framework (with a tiny bit of Scala) and looking to use testing frameworks like Jasmine (and for the scala scalatest or JUnit)?

i found [this](http://edspencer.net/2013/07/28/jasmine-and-jenkins-continuous-integration/) post which describes a way to set CI up with Jasmine:Guard and Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

[This plugin](https://github.com/joescii/sbt-jasmine-plugin) integrates Jasmine with Play.
 
[This one](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/play-plugin) integrates Jenkins with Play.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [SBT plugin for Jasmine](https://github.com/joescii/sbt-jasmine-plugin). I used it recently with Play 2.2.3 based on [this excellent guide by Pere Villega](http://perevillega.com/post/2013/01/26/26/executing-jasmine-tests-in-play-204/) and was able to run the Jasmine tests together with the other tests using `play test`. You should be able to execute them this way using a CI server without much effort.

Comment: yes, were looking at installing this too. this allows Jasmine to integrate with Play, but does it offer CI?